# Como usar a função 'len' num template em python - Flask

Tags: python, template, flask

Tenho uma AppWeb em python-Flask que gostaria de mostra a quantidade de jogadores online, só que estou meio perdido nessa parte já tentei {% len(data) %} e {% data|length %} e nenhum dois métodos teve resultado. se alguém poder me ajuda nessa parte.

Observação: a variavel "data" me traz um dicionario json do servido do jogo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

codigo em html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>    
    <title>Infinite Fight Brasil</title>    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}">



</head>
<body>
    {% extends "bootstrap/base.html" %}
        {% block  content %}


        <div id="carregando" class="center" align="center">
            <br><br><iframe src='https://www.liveflightapp.com/embed?key=d92f147c-1300-462f-84a0-e198ff0aeb01' width='80%'height='500px' frameborder='0' scrolling='no'></iframe>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        <br>
        <br>



        <div id="quant">
            <h2> No momento a xxx online nesse momento.</h2>
        </div>

        <br>

        <div class="container">
            <table id="customers">
                <tr>
                    <th>Piloto</th>
                    <th>Voo</th>
                    <th>DEP - ARR</th>
                    <th>Altitude</th>
                    <th>Velocidade</th>
                    <th>Online</th>

                </tr>
                {% for i in range(930) %}
                    {% if "IFBR" in data[i]["DisplayName"] %}
                    <tr>
                        <td>{{data[i]["DisplayName"]}}</td>
                        <td>{{data[i]["CallSign"]}}</td>
                        <td>--------</td>
                        <td>{{"{0:.0f} ft".format (data[i]["Altitude"])}}</td>
                        <td>{{"{0:.0f} kts".format (data[i]['Speed'])}}</td>
                        <td>Expert Server</td>                    
                    </tr>

                    {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            </table>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
        </div>
        {% endblock %}

<br>
<br>        
</body>
</html>
-->
```

parte do flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from models.database import BancoDados

app = Flask(__name__)
Bootstrap(app)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', data=BancoDados.total())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: Boa noite, tenta isso -> `{% if data|length > 1 %}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simples, basta usar o filtro do próprio jinja2:

```
<h2> No momento a {{ data|length }} online nesse momento.</h2>
```

Ou também:

```
<h2> No momento a {{ data|count }} online nesse momento.</h2>
```

Mesma coisa para o "for":

```
{% for i in range(data|length) %}
```